# Moving to the UK as self-employed, or other alternatives

Tags: united-kingdom, self-employment

My brother (extra-EEA) works in the UK and I would like to move to the UK as well. I am a freelance, self-employed and would continue my normal job remotely that would allow me to pay for the living expenses. What is the best way to do this given that I am an extra-EEA?

I was thinking to apply for a job online (reed.co.uk, gumtree jobs) that would sponsor me working in the UK - but this seems highly improbable given that I am not physically in the UK.

I have a university degree in foreign languages, and would also be available to get to the UK for a Masters provided that after that staying in the UK would be simpler.

I looked at the self-employment procedure and it looks like I would need to invest £50000 or more in the UK to come to the UK as an entrepreneur. Is there any alternative to this?

Any advice will be most appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your simplest option may be to enroll on a Masters program and enter the UK as a student. However, your options for remaining after the course ends are limited.

You can apply for a job in the UK from where you are now but the employer would have to show they cannot readily fill the vacancy with an EEA applicant in order to sponsor your visa.